# Does tapasya remove even dhatus?

Tags: yoga, tantra, ayurveda

Tapasya cleanses body of all toxins, especially solid, liquid, fat, pitta and kapha natured, (as well as perhaps nadis as well, though I'm not sure about this) by Divine purifying rays of the Sun, so that only vayu, Vata/prana remains, can freely flow inside body without any blockage, as well as ensures that purusha can come and reside in body, nadis, but does it end up removing all dhatus including ojas/Tejas, as well, as side effect/byproduct, while cleansing the body? Is that why alternative purifying methods such as nadi shuddi, various Pranayama which in turn stimulate nadis to produce heat/agni to purify, sweat out only toxins, from within, are more endorsed/popularised/mainstream than tapasya?

Comment: what do you mean by it removes Ojas?

Comment: Tejas or Ojas are not Dhatus and no by Tapasya Tejas is not destroyed in fact it is created

Comment: Oh didn't knew, thanks for the info

Comment: But what about dhatus? Does it remove all kapha, pitta etc dhatus?